# scala implicit conversion doesn't work

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit, implicits

I discover a strange phenomenon:

```
class A {
  val dual: A = this
  object T {
    implicit def doubleDual(t: T): dual.dual.T = t.asInstanceOf[dual.dual.T]
    implicit def justForTest(t: T): Int = 777
  }
  class T
}
val a = new A
val t = new a.T
// import a.T._
val x: Int = t //this works!
val t1: a.dual.dual.T = t //this doesn't work!
```

According to implicit search rule, the method `doubleDual` in `object T` should be applied. But it doesn't. I have to import `a.T._` manually. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is "the same name"!

```
class A {
  val dual: A = this
  object T {
    implicit def doubleDual(t: T): dual.dual.T = t.asInstanceOf[dual.dual.T]
  }
  class T
}
val a = new A
val t = new a.T
import a.T.doubleDual  //
import a.dual.dual.T.doubleDual  //the same name!
val t1: a.dual.dual.T = t // won't compile
```

But after rename:

```
import a.T.doubleDual  //
import a.dual.dual.T.{doubleDual => dd}  // different name!
val t1: a.dual.dual.T = t // can compile
```

Comment: Those imports change the situation a lot, unfortunately. And it's based on the part of my answer which I've got wrong :(

Comment: According to implicit search rule, compiler will automatically import `a.T._` and `a.dual.dual.T._`. And the two conflict name `doubleDual` cause this two same-name method useless. Just like my manually import.

Answer (score 1):

> According to implicit search rule, the method doubleDual in object T should be applied.

It looks to me like <s>the search should find *two* implicits: `a.T.doubleDual` and `a.dual.dual.T.doubleDual` The question is why it doesn't give "implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous" error. Maybe because they have the same name?</s>

No, that's wrong, `a.dual.dual.T.doubleDual` has a wrong type. But I still suspect the problem may be related to the `T` object appearing twice when searching for `a.T` and `a.dual.dual.T`. It's just that this would be a compiler bug, unless I missed something else.